# Delay when printing

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, telerik-reporting

I used this code to print a receipt in my WPF application:

```
Receipt _receiptReport = new Receipt();
System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings printerSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController standardPrintController = new System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController();
Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor reportProcessor = new Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor();
reportProcessor.PrintController = standardPrintController;
Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource instanceReportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();
instanceReportSource.ReportDocument = _receiptReport;
reportProcessor.PrintReport(instanceReportSource, printerSettings);
```

But there is a delay when printing. Is there anything wrong with this code or is there another way to print faster?

Comment: In order to answer this question, we need to quantify what you mean by 'delay'.  Also -- what kind of printer you have, how it's connected, and what the Receipt report looks like -- all that factors in.  Please clarify.

Comment: I used receipt printer (Tysso PRP-250), the report is a receipt report contain invoice items. But tested it with different printers and the delay in all of them